# Время в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Хочу составить запрос на вывод из таблицы users только те id, у которых значение online "используется time() в php коде" больше, чем time()-900.
Только всё это нужно сделать в sql запросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ts - время последнего доступа

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ts > now() - 900
```

более подробнее о [функциях дата/время](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Благодарю:-)

Answer (score 2):

Раз надо время из PHP получить, то сделаем как-то так:

```
<?php
$currentTime = time() - 900;

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ts > ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $currentTime);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // ... работа, работа, работа
}
?>
```

Comment: возможно так даже лучше... так как меньше нагружаем сервер БД.